# Ajax autosearch is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxSearch() {
     // alert('hai');
        var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
     // alert(input_data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search/auto_search",
            data1: {search_data:input_data},
            success: function(data1) {
                alert(data1);
                // return success
                if (data1.length > 0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

View:

```
<div class="something">
    <input name="search_data" id="search_data" type="text" onkeyup="ajaxSearch();">
     <div id="suggestions">
         <div id="autoSuggestionsList"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function auto_search() {

    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
  //echo "aaaaaaaaaaaa".$search_data; die();
 // print_r($search_data);  die();
    $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);
 // print_r($query);  die();
 // if (!empty($query)) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            echo $row->uid.'</br>'  ;
            echo  $row->name ;
        }
...
```

when  i alert  the data1 in jquery,  the  result is entire view  that is  code that is  given in  view. What is the problem with this code? Can you explain  this and provide a solution for this problem? Controller, Model and jquery is given above.

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong then you are trying for autocomplete box.and as per my experice instead of following code use array to store your data and convert it to json and then send that json to browser then then fill that array to autolist.

```
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
       echo $row->uid.'</br>'  ;
        echo  $row->name ;
   }
```

instead of above code use following code.

```
  $response = array();
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
    $response[] = array('uid'=>$row->uid,'name'=>$row->name);
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
```

I hope it will help you and need any help then commnet it.

Answer (score 0):

some framework Controller will auto load view file to display, maybe you need to stop it.

or try to add exit();

```
public function auto_search() {

    //your code
exit();
}
```

remark : think about ajax retrun json or html,

Comment: Controller will auto load view file to display .How to stop this issue??